# MS SQL Server LEFT JOIN not Producing expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a LEFT JOIN on two tables but I am not sure why the LEFT JOIN is not working as expected.

```
select * from table1
```

| dealer_id | org_id | product_id | zipcode | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 1001 | 2 |
| 2001 | 1 | 2 | 1004 | 5 |
| 2001 | 1 | 2 | 1001 | 8 |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 1009 | 8 |
| 2002 | 1 | 3 | 1001 | 8 |
| 2002 | 1 | 1 | 1009 | 9 |

```
select * from table2
```

| org_id | product_id | zipcode | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1001 | 23 |
| 1 | 2 | 1004 | 34 |
| 1 | 2 | 1001 | 22 |
| 2 | 1 | 9001 | 23 |
| 1 | 3 | 1001 | 45 |

The query I am using is,

```
SELECT a.dealer_id, 
    a.org_id, 
    a.product_id, 
    a.zipcode, 
    b.zipcode AS mapped_code, 
    a.qty
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.org_id = b.org_id 
                   AND a.product_id = b.product_id 
                   AND a.zipcode = b.zipcode
```

The results that I am expecting is,

| dealer_id | org_id | product_id | zipcode | customer_id | mapped_code | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 1001 | 23 | 1001 | 2 |
| 2001 | 1 | 2 | 1004 | 34 | 1001 | 5 |
| 2001 | 1 | 2 | 1001 | 22 | 1001 | 8 |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 1009 | NULL | NULL | 8 |
| 2002 | 1 | 3 | 1001 | 45 | 1001 | 8 |
| 2002 | 1 | 1 | 1009 | NULL | NULL | 9 |

However, I am getting the following results, I even tried with LEFT OUTER and its the same,

| dealer_id | org_id | product_id | zipcode | customer_id | mapped_code | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 1001 | 23 | 1001 | 2 |
| 2001 | 1 | 2 | 1004 | 34 | 1001 | 5 |
| 2001 | 1 | 2 | 1001 | 22 | 1001 | 8 |
| 2002 | 1 | 3 | 1001 | 45 | 1001 | 8 |

I tried, using only single condition on the join and it works, however it does not work with the three conditions that I have.

I may be doing something wrong.

Any pointers to this is appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server

Comment: Have you noticed that you are not using table2 in your sql statement. You are using two times table1 only.

Comment: @BerndOtt My Bad, I have updated the query in the question.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a `where` clause?  A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No I do not have any where clause. This is it. I tried placing all the conditions in where as well and it produces the same result. Like I mentioned, if I add only one condition in the join then it works.

Comment: can you share the exact query because 
`SELECT a.dealer_id, 
    a.org_id, 
    a.product_id, 
    a.zipcode, 
    b.zipcode AS mapped_code, 
    a.qty
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.org_id = b.org_id 
                   AND a.product_id = b.product_id 
                   AND a.zipcode = b.zipcode`
would give a different result

Comment: The only way that your query does not produce the "desired result" is when you assume too much - that is, if your join logic is incorrect or if you the rows you expect simply do not exist in the unpreserved (table2) table. You say a join with one column works. So add the other 2 columns from table2 into the select list to see what those columns contain to better understand your data.

Comment: After adding the b.customer_id column, I get the expected result.

Comment: If I literally put `create table` statements above each piece of sample data, and then `insert` that data for both tables, I get exactly your expected results. Since we already know you made one typo in the query, it's clear that *you have not run that query against the given sample data*. Rather than frustrate everyone with having to guess, please create some sample data (as `create`/`insert` statements) and a query *that you have actually run against that data* and know it produces the results you claim.

Comment: The query you are showing cannot result in less rows than are in table1. If you do get less rows, then your real query is different from the one you are showing us. (Or you are using a tool that only shows the first n result rows.)

Comment: Hi Guys @ThorstenKettner,! I understand your points but unfortunately I cannot share the exact query or the data that is causing this. Even I was sure that the LEFT JOIN would work when I wrote the actual SQL Query. But it does not for some reason. I will just close this question for now and will brainstorm more on this one. I will share if I find anything specific. Thanks ✌️

Comment: At a guess, an extra `WHERE` clause is filtering `table2`, as mentioned by @GordonLinoff

Comment: @SMor Same as above :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Same as above :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your SQL isn't formed correctly...

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
    dealer_id VARCHAR(10)
    , org_id INT 
    , product_id INT
    , zipcode VARCHAR(10)
    , qty INT
)

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(2001,1,1,1001,2)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(2001,1,2,1004,5)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(2001,1,2,1001,8)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(2001,1,1,1009,8)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(2002,1,3,1001,8)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(2002,1,1,1009,9)

DECLARE @table2 TABLE
(
    org_id INT 
    , product_id INT
    , zipcode VARCHAR(10)
    , customer_id INT
)

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES(1,1,1001,23)
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES(1,2,1004,34)
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES(1,2,1001,22)
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES(2,1,9001,23)
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES(1,3,1001,45)

SELECT a.dealer_id, 
    a.org_id, 
    a.product_id, 
    b.customer_id,
    a.zipcode, 
    b.zipcode AS mapped_code, 
    a.qty
FROM @table1 a
LEFT JOIN @table2 b ON a.org_id = b.org_id 
                   AND a.product_id = b.product_id 
                   AND a.zipcode = b.zipcode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use LEFT JOIN all rows of left table will be returned. However, in the Right table, Matching records are returned. Your result is correct